# Uso de mustache-express4

Tags: nodejs, express

Soy novato con `express` y `mustache`, pero no entiendo el error:

El `index.js`

```
const join = require( 'path' ).join;
const EX = require( 'express' );
const MiniModule = require( './mini' );

var app = EX( );

app.engine( 'must', require( 'mustache-express4' ) );
app.set( 'views', join( __dirname, 'views' ) );
app.set( 'view engine', 'must' );

app.use( MiniModule );

app.listen( 8080 );
```

y el `mini.js`

```
const EX = require( 'express' );

var Router = EX.Router( );

Router.get( '/login.html', function( req, res ) {
  res.render( 'login.must', { title: 'Prueba de mustache' } );
} );

module.exports = Router;
```

La plantilla que intento *renderizar* es muy simple:

Archivo `login.must`:

```
<html>
<head><title>{{title}}</title></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

La jerarquía de directorios del proyecto es la siguiente:

```
Proyecto/
+-node_modules/
| +- ...
+-src/
  +-index.js
  +-mini.js
  +-views/
    +-login.must
```

Al ejecutar el `index.js`, no muestra ningún error. El servidor arranca y queda a la escucha en el puerto `8080`.

**Pero**... en cuanto intento acceder, con el navegador, a

```
localhost:8080/login.html
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

> fs.js:952
>   return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path), options.encoding);
>   -------------------^
>    
>   TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
>      at TypeError (native)
>      at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:952:18)
>      at loadPartials (Proyecto/node_modules/mustache-express4/lib/mustache-express.js:11:14)
>      at Proyecto/node_modules/mustache-express4/lib/mustache-express.js:28:63
>      at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:446:3)

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Como lo soluciono ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

- Utilizas `must` cuando debe ser `mustache`.
- Olvidaste establecer el directorio de vistas parciales.

> ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Primero, cambia `must` por `mustache`:

```
app.engine( 'mustache', require( 'mustache-express4' ) );
app.set( 'views', join( __dirname, 'views' ) );
app.set( 'view engine', 'mustache' );
```

Además, Mustache te pide que establezcas el directorio de vistas parciales para que pueda buscar allí si se usa una. Por ende, como segunda cosa debes agregar el directorio de vistas parciales:

```
app.set('partials', join(__dirname, 'views/partials'));
```